# How can I read the File from this Site?

Tags: php, m3u8

i have make a php i want see the live stream

Live Stream from here https://www.tv8.com.tr/canli-yayin

i have mak a php to read the m3u link but it's not work

this is my php

```
<?php

$link = "https://www.tv8.com.tr/canli-yayin";
$veri = file_get_contents($link);
preg_match('#file: "(.*?)"#', $veri,$veritemp); 

echo $veritemp[1];

?>
```

And The Answer over Xammp

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\4.php on line 7

Comment: you should **never** mix php and js. They're executed differently and are two different languages

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Whats wrong in my php?

Comment: @treyBake i havent mix php and js! First Code is from the Website, the second from my php to watch the livestream. If i copy the m3u8 link, this works only any hours after this change the link after st= yesterday st=WMsuD2A9CKPrYfCFEMTt_Q&e=1567768496 and today ?st=ntsdcJnO_YoSeUIwBjLAIw&e=1567885970

Comment: Olmazz kardes never . impossible with PHP

Comment: why should'nt work it?